# .Net Core Razor Pages - Partial View with multiple objects

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I’m pretty new to .Net Core, EF Core & Razor pages.

I have a form which uses posts to a razor page. The page model has three bound properties, two of which are EF Models (I use inheritance to only bind safe properties) and one is just a string:

```
 [BindProperty]
 public Models.BaseEvent _Event { get; set; }

 [BindProperty]
 [Display(Name = "Venue Search")]
 public string _VenueSearch { get; set; }

 [BindProperty]
 public Models.BaseVenue _Venue { get; set; }
```

I then have a form, used to create an event. When adding information about the event, they can either choose an existing venue, using the venue search, or add a new one. _VenueSearch is bound only to automatically re-populate the form if there is an error. I use jquery to perform autocomplete on the field.

However, I’m trying to put the form into a partial, but I have no idea how to pass in _Event, _VenueSearch & _Venue?

```
<form method="post">
            <input id="venueid" type="hidden" asp-for="_Venue.VenueID" />
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="_Event.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="_Event.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="_Event.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="_Event.StartDateTime" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="_Event.StartDateTime" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="_Event.StartDateTime" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="_Event.EndDateTime" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="_Event.EndDateTime" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="_Event.EndDateTime" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div id="search-container" class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="_VenueSearch" class="control-label"></label>
                <input id="venue" asp-for="_VenueSearch" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="_VenueSearch" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="_Venue.Name" class="control-label">Venue Name</label>
                <input id="venue-name" asp-for="_Venue.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="_Venue.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="_Venue.Address" class="control-label">Venue Address</label>
                <input id="venue-address" asp-for="_Venue.Address" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="_Venue.Address" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="_Venue.City" class="control-label">Venue City</label>
                <input id="venue-city" asp-for="_Venue.City" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="_Venue.City" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="_Venue.PostCode" class="control-label">Venue Postcode</label>
                <input id="venue-postcode" asp-for="_Venue.PostCode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="_Venue.PostCode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="_Event.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <textarea asp-for="_Event.Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="_Event.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="_Event.AgeRestriction" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="_Event.AgeRestriction" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="_Event.AgeRestriction" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create Event" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

How would I put this in a partial so that I still have access to the two models and string (_Event, _Venue & _VenueSearch. I haven’t included the javascript autocomplete code as its irrelevant to this post.

I want to use a partial as both my create/edit pages will use the same form, so I don’t see the point of duplication.

Thanks in advance for any help

Matt

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view model and includes the objects which query from database , when loading the partial view ,directly pass the view model to partial view :

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("viewName", model:Model.YourModel)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This is exactly what I thought I would have to do.  But making a view model just so that I can pass objects to a partial view just seems crazy to me, its a shame that partials can't have access to the same data that your standard page view has.

Comment: Not really , you can load the partial view from cs codes :https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/325/partials-and-ajax-in-razor-pages . So that you don't need to create view model , directly correct data from your EF model and at last pass data to partial view .